# Parse Objective C library crashes on [PFInternalUtils installationId]

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, parse-platform

I'm running the latest iOS Objective C SDK from Parse.com, version 1.4.2
I am getting frequent crashes on a fresh install with the following backtrace. It happens in the simulator, on my debug device, and in the release/production version of my app.

```
Thread 2 Crashed:
1   libobjc.A.dylib objc_msgSend + 6
2   Foundation  -[NSString getExternalRepresentation:extendedAttributes:forWritingToURLOrPath:usingEncoding:error:] + 312
3   Foundation  writeStringToURLOrPath + 44
4   Foundation  -[NSString writeToFile:atomically:encoding:error:] + 22
5   Aftermath   +[PFInternalUtils installationId] (PFInternalUtils.m:308)
6   Aftermath   +[PFNetworkCommandRunner createRequest:] (PFNetworkCommandRunner.m:62)
7   Aftermath   +[PFNetworkCommandRunner runCommandAsync:inOperation:] (PFNetworkCommandRunner.m:133)
8   Aftermath   +[PFRetryingCommandRunner runCommandAsync:inOperation:attemptsMade:delay:] (PFRetryingCommandRunner.m:42)
9   Aftermath   +[PFRetryingCommandRunner runCommandAsync:inOperation:] (PFRetryingCommandRunner.m:35)
10  Aftermath   +[PFCachedCommandRunner runCommandAsync:inOperation:cachePolicy:maxCacheAge:] (PFCachedCommandRunner.m:83)
11  Aftermath   __64-[PFQuery findAsyncWithCachePolicy:conditions:limit:skip:after:]_block_invoke (PFQuery.m:1292)
12  Aftermath   __48-[BFTask continueWithExecutor:withSuccessBlock:]_block_invoke (BFTask.m:335)
13  Aftermath   __41-[BFTask continueWithExecutor:withBlock:]_block_invoke_2 (BFTask.m:287)
```

Comment: I'm experiencing a similar error.  Using NSZombieEnabled, I traced my problem back to a custom category on UIFont.  Still debugging though.  Have you figured out what was wrong in your project?

Comment: Nope, haven't figured out my problems yet -- you should please chime in on the official support request to the Parse team to let them know I'm not the only one: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1548203598729083 . And I'm not even using UIKit at all: my game is a OpenGL game, so it's definitely not related to that, but perhaps there was something about your UIFont category, like a threaded operation, which was at fault?

Comment: I think mine had to do with an NSString object getting sent a message after deallocation, but I probably won't look into this more until after Thanksgiving.  Did you run your application with NSZombieEnabled to try and trace the problem?  Also, my similar crash was so infrequent I had trouble reproducing it consistently.  I see yours is happening quite frequently though.

Comment: Mine is very frequent when you consider all the users of my app, but very hard to reproduce alone by just me. I've tried Zombies, but of course can't seem to get a reproduction when they're enabled =/

Comment: Can you track the crash down to a specific section of code? If so, could you post that please?

Comment: I've already posted the full stack trace. It happens on a separate thread, outside my run loop and inside the Parse SDK, so I'm not quite sure how I'm supposed to track it down since it's not happening within my code...

Comment: Pretty sure this is a Parse SDK bug.  I am able to reproduce *sometimes* on an initial install.  I posted my backtrace here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26395731/ios-8-crashing-in-a-weird-pattern/27712139

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, there was a bug in SDK 1.4.2 back in the day.
The current version (at the time of writing this answer) is 1.7.5, which has this problem fixed.

You can update the SDK by downloading the package from https://parse.com/docs/downloads
or via Cocoapods: https://cocoapods.org/pods/Parse